# Inner UI Table View not scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

I have a nested tableview setup, where each parent tableViewCell contains a tableview of it's own. Each parent tableViewCell, expands or collapses accordingly when it's selected. However once the cell is expanded, the tableView of the cell is not scrollable. only parent tableView's scroll is performed.
Any help would be much appreciated!

/* sub 0, sub 1... table view is not scrolling */

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are taking to implement the design is unnecessarily complicated and will create problems like this. The design you have can be very easily solved using one `UITableView` instance (without nesting another into all of it's `UITableViewCell` instances.

First of all, Delete your nested `UITableView` instance that's inside a `UITableViewCell`.

See following implementation -

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var expandedSections: Set<Int> = Set()
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if expandedSections.contains(section) {
            return 10 // 1 (parentRow) + number of subrows
        } else {
            return 1 // (parentRow)
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            // return parentCell
        } else {
            // return subrowCell (with indexPath.row - 1 as index)
        }
    }

    func expandSection(_ section: Int) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        if expandedSections.insert(section).inserted {
            tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: section), with: .automatic)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    
    func collapseSection(_ section: Int) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        if expandedSections.remove(section) != nil {
            tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: section), with: .automatic)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    
}
```